# Definir formato do componente MatDatePicker

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular, typescript, angular-material

### Como definir o formato do componente [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) em Angular 6.

Em minha aplicação em Angular 6, estou trabalhando com o banco de dados **Cloud Firestore** do [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). Ao realizar uma consulta de documentos, quando o documento possui um campo do tipo `Timestamp` retornando uma data, não carrega a data no componente **DatePicker** e então não é exibido na tela.

Visto que o componente **DatePicker** espera por um objeto do tipo `Date` e não um objeto do tipo `Timestamp`, sendo assim não é carregado no componente e não é exibido na tela.

Existe uma forma de efetuar a tipagem deste componente para receber um objeto do tipo `Timestamp` ao invés de um objeto do tipo `Date`?

**form.component.html:**

```
        <mat-form-field class="mr-sm-24" fxFlex>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker" formControlName="startDate" placeholder="Data de ínicio">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

**form.component.ts:**

```
import { Todo } from 'app/main/gerenciamento/todo/todo.model';

todo: Todo;

createTodoForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        'id': [this.todo.id],
        'title': [this.todo.title],
        'notes': [this.todo.notes],
        'startDate': [this.todo.startDate],
        'dueDate': [this.todo.dueDate],
        'completed': [this.todo.completed],
        'starred': [this.todo.starred],
        'important': [this.todo.important],
        'deleted': [this.todo.deleted],
        'tags': [this.todo.tags],
        'tagList': [this.todo.tagList]
    });
}
```

**todo.model.ts:**

```
export class Todo {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    notes: string;
    startDate: string;
    dueDate: string;
    completed: boolean;
    starred: boolean;
    important: boolean;
    deleted: boolean;
    tags: {};
    tagList: [
        {
            'id': number,
            'name': string,
            'label': string,
            'color': string
        }
    ];

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param todo
     */
    constructor(todo) {
        {
            this.id = todo.id;
            this.title = todo.title;
            this.notes = todo.notes;
            this.startDate = todo.startDate && todo.startDate.toDate();
            this.dueDate = todo.dueDate && todo.dueDate.toDate();
            this.completed = todo.completed;
            this.starred = todo.starred;
            this.important = todo.important;
            this.deleted = todo.deleted;
            this.tags = todo.tags || {};
            this.tagList = todo.tagList || [];
        }
    }
```

No model estou tendo que chamar a função `toDate()`, pois o retorno do **Cloud Firestore** é um `Timestamp` ao invés de um `Date`, e eu preciso do objeto Date pois o componente não aceita um valor do tipo `Timestamp`.

Acontece que nem todos os documentos tem o campo com a data preenchida, então quando carregado e chamado a função `toDate()` ocorre erro porque vem `null`.

Antes das atualizações que fiz das dependências do `package.json` do NodeJS, o valor retornado era um objeto do tipo `Date`, agora está retornando um objeto `Timestamp`.

**Solução esperada:**

1. Qual a melhor solução para evitar erros?
2. Consigo alterar a tipagem do componente para receber um `Timestamp`
   ao invés de um `Date` por padrão?

Comment: você esta recebendo uma string de Timestamp do banco como e essa string? tive que passar por isso semana passada a forma que encontrei de resolver isso foi fazendo um parse dessa string.